# Using Multiple ListViews in a Single Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to create an Activity that retrieves a set of Notes stored in the database. Now, depending on the date set for each note, I want to partition the ListView, based on Notes for Today, Tomorrow and Upcoming(each having their own TextView in between the ListView of the Notes).

Should I create 3 separate ListViews? Will it work? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to show the items in a `ListView` grouped by some categories (Today, Tormorrow, etc). If this is so, then you could use the [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) which can group data in categories.

(If you don't need the "expandable" behaviour, then this can be disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use the [Sticky List Headers](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) instead a ExpandableListView to add sections to your list view. You can customize the sections views by extending your adapter from StickyListHeadersAdapter and override the getHeaderId and getHeaderView methods.

```
@Override public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HeaderViewHolder holder;
    //...

@Override
public long getHeaderId(int position) {
     // ...
}
```

Comment: That's pretty neat, I'll check it out but I don't know how to integrate github code into my project. Thanks though!

Comment: Is very simple. First clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders.git` and then, import the library proyect: file -> new -> project -> android project from existing source.